# Pass for vs Pass by

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I am confused between for and by for the following question :

> What passes ____ education today is just an exercise in memory
>   building.
>
> a.) in b.) for c.) about d.) by

[Pass by](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pass-by)

[Pass for](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pass-for)

[Macmillan Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

Definitely **pass for**. As your own source says:

> to be accepted, wrongly, as being a particular type of person or thing

In your sentence, an exercise in memory building is mistaken for education.

Pass by means *to go by physically*. Time can also "pass by", meaning it is happening: The seconds passed by.